# Using instanced geometry in Maya

Tags: python, 3d, instance, maya, autodesk

I've been experimenting with the use of instanced geometry in Maya and am not understanding the node associations that result from the creation of a simple scene:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

polyCubeTemplate = cmds.polyCube(n="polyCubeTemplate", w=0.1, h=0.4, d=0.4)
cmds.setAttr("polyCubeTemplate.visibility", 0)

cube = cmds.instance(polyCubeTemplate[0], n="pCube0")
cmds.move(-0.75, -1.5, 7.0, "pCube0")
cmds.setAttr("pCube0.visibility", 1)
cubeSG = cmds.sets(n="set0", renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True)
cubeShader = cmds.shadingNode("mia_material_x_passes", asShader=True, n="mia_material_x_passes0")
cmds.setAttr(cubeShader+".diffuse",0.003921569,0.003921569,0.0, type="double3")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miPhotonShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miShadowShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miMaterialShader")
cmds.sets(cube[0], edit=True, forceElement=cubeSG)

cube = cmds.instance(polyCubeTemplate[0], n="pCube1")
cmds.move(-0.75, -1.0, 7.0, "pCube1")
cmds.setAttr("pCube1.visibility", 1)
cubeSG = cmds.sets(n="set1", renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True)
cubeShader = cmds.shadingNode("mia_material_x_passes", asShader=True, n="mia_material_x_passes1")
cmds.setAttr(cubeShader+".diffuse",0.011764706,0.011764706,0.0, type="double3")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miPhotonShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miShadowShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miMaterialShader")
cmds.sets(cube[0], edit=True, forceElement=cubeSG)
```

When *pCube0* is selected in the scene, the attribute editor shows the following list of nodes:

- transform node *pCube0*
- shape / mesh node *polyCubeTemplateShape*
- object node *polyCube1*
- default shading group node *initialShadingGroup*
- default material node *lambert1*
- mental ray material node *mia_material_x_passes0*
- mental ray material node *mia_material_x_passes1*
- a repeat (?) of the shape / mesh node *polyCubeTemplateShape*

[image]

A non-instanced version of the above is

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cube = cmds.polyCube(n="pCube0", w=0.1, h=0.4, d=0.4)
cmds.setAttr(cube[0]+".translateX",-0.75)
cmds.setAttr(cube[0]+".translateY",-1.5)
cmds.setAttr(cube[0]+".translateZ",7.0)
cubeSG = cmds.sets(n="set0", renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True)
cubeShader = cmds.shadingNode("mia_material_x_passes", asShader=True, n="mia_material_x_passes0")
cmds.setAttr(cubeShader+".diffuse",0.003921569,0.003921569,0.0, type="double3")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miPhotonShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miShadowShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miMaterialShader")
cmds.sets(cube[0], edit=True, forceElement=cubeSG)

cube = cmds.polyCube(n="pCube1", w=0.1, h=0.4, d=0.4)
cmds.setAttr(cube[0]+".translateX",-0.75)
cmds.setAttr(cube[0]+".translateY",-1.0)
cmds.setAttr(cube[0]+".translateZ",7.0)
cubeSG = cmds.sets(n="set1", renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True)
cubeShader = cmds.shadingNode("mia_material_x_passes", asShader=True, n="mia_material_x_passes1")
cmds.setAttr(cubeShader+".diffuse",0.011764706,0.011764706,0.0, type="double3")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miPhotonShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miShadowShader")
cmds.connectAttr(cubeShader+".message",cubeSG+".miMaterialShader")
cmds.sets(cube[0], edit=True, forceElement=cubeSG)
```

Selecting *pCube0* in this scene yields the node list

- transform node *pCube0*
- shape / mesh node *polyCube0Shape*
- object node *polyCube1*
- mental ray material node *mia_material_x_passes0*

This is the kind of structure I'd like to see in the instanced scene.

So I have three questions:

1. In the case of the instanced scene, why has *pCube0* 'picked up' a copy of *pCube1*'s material node (*mia_material_x_passes1*)? (Are these mental ray material nodes somehow plugged into the shared parent / template polyCube?)
2. What explains the presence of the repeat of the shape / mesh node *polyCubeTemplateShape*?
3. How can I instance properly so as to avoid this kind of messy node structure?

Answer (score 1):

Instancing in Maya is implemented by parenting the same shape node to multiple transforms: that's why you see the copy.  The material assignment is handled by the connections off of `.instObjectGroups` on the shape, which point subsets of the geometry to different `shadingEngine` nodes (the "SG" nodes in your hypergraph).  A shadingEngine is, however, just a set which has a specialized collection to shader (the shader balls in the materials UI or the attrib editor).  The actual 'shader' has a lot of attributes, depending on the shader type and its settings.  In your case it appears there are two different shaders, one for each instance, with different colors.

I looks like the original scene included an invisible copy of the object as a template and then had two visible instances. Thats not uncommon when people want a convenient way to edit a 'master' copy of geometry which is duplicated in many different places at different sizes and orientations.  Editing the actual template shape -- grabbing and moving a vert, say -- will update all of the copies at the same time.

This is all completely vanilla Maya. It's how an instanced scene looks when you troll the file

Comment: So it appears that when instancing, the shared (parent) shape node is connected to each of the instanced objects' shading group nodes: (polyCubeTemplateShape connection to initialShadingGroup) polyCubeTemplateShape.instObjGroups[0] -> initialShadingGroup.dagSetMembers[0]
(polyCubeTemplateShape connection to set0 shading group) polyCubeTemplateShape.instObjGroups[1] -> set0.dagSetMembers[0]
(polyCubeTemplateShape connection to set1 shading group) polyCubeTemplateShape.instObjGroups[2] -> set1.dagSetMembers[1]. My problem: the rendering time is far greater for the instanced scene.

Comment: Far greater than non-instanced?

Comment: Apparently. I've done a crude test. The uninstanced and instanced scenes contain the same geometry and shading sets (4613 polycubes; 4613 shading sets), except the instanced scene contains 7 invisible polycube parents. Here are the results of three renders (times in seconds, uninstanced times listed first): 2K (24s, 54s); 2K + FG (38s, 68s); 2K + FG + Quality = 4 (88s, 96s). I understood that instanced scenes generally rendered much faster than unistanced ones. Am I missing something?

Comment: @svenpables depends on what you render with. Nothing says instancing has to be faster. Its just faster to update. If you raytrace there's really no benefit from the instances except maybe some memory savings.

Comment: @joojaa, so is there anything I can do to restructure / reformat / reconfigure my geometry to reduce render times? The production scene I'm working on includes over 300K polycubes and the render times for a typical frame on a six-core machine are crazy (hours).